# Zend Framework problem with Zend_Layout

Tags: php, zend-framework

How can I create something like: $this->layout()->sidebar, I'm trying for about 4 hours...but it doesn't work for me!Can you give me an example?

Comment: Your purpose is not clear. What is your final target?

Comment: i want to create a layout helper, sa when i write $this->layout()->sidebar, toretrive some html..like $this->layout()->content, how can i to that?what i need to do?i hope you got it now :)

Comment: Create a view helper and use it normally in your layout code/view code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not certain what you are trying to do - but maybe this code that I'm using would help.

```
// setup the info column into the placeholder
$this->placeholder('rightcol')
     ->set($this->render('index/view_infoCol.phtml'));

// later in the layout template
echo $this->placeholder('rightcol');
```

Answer (score 0):

use [setResponseSegment](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html)('sidebar') in you controller to make $this->layout()->sidebar work...

Answer (score 0):

You could use this:

In your controller:

```
$this->_response->insert('sidebar', $this->view->render('sidebar.phtml'));
```

In your layout:

```
<?=$this->layout()->sidebar;?>
```